# How to make Virtual Host redirect any domain to the appropriate folder?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

How to make Virtual Host redirect any domain to the appropriate folder?
My A-record can redirect all (*) sub domains of domain.com to my ip.

How to make smth like this:

```
domain.com => /var/www/domain.com
sub.domain.com => /var/www/sub.domain.com
sub.sub.domain.com => /var/www/sub.sub.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

mod_vhost_alias

> This module creates dynamically configured virtual hosts, by allowing
>   the IP address and/or the Host: header of the HTTP request to be used
>   as part of the pathname to determine what files to serve. This allows
>   for easy use of a huge number of virtual hosts with similar
>   configurations.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html